# Formatação de gramas ou quilogramas em UITextfield no Swift 5

Tags: swift, uitextfield

procurei sobre isso no stack overflow e nao encontrei uma solução plausível. Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato!.

O objetivo:
Preciso formatar um textfield para aceitar valores em gramas ou kilogramas. por exemplo:

- Valor inserido no Textfield: 0850
- Valor formatado no Textfield: 0,850 Kg

Exemplo 2:

- Valor inserido no Textfield: 850
- Valor formatado no Textfield: 0,850 Kg

Comment: Fala Leonardo, bem vindo ao site. Para facilitar quem for responder de entender sua dúvida, seria legal você editar sua pergunta e adicionar mais alguns detalhes. Como por exemplo: O que você já tentou fazer? Poderia colocar o trecho de código referente? Deu algum erro? Em qual linha? Poderia botar mais exemplos de entrada/saída para mostrar o comportamento desejado? Se puder colocar o comportamento (errado) que você teve quando tentou fazer seria bem útil também. Um abraço e boa sorte!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o `UnitMass.grams`

```swift
    public func formatWeight(weightInKgs: Double) -> String {
        let mformatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        mformatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
        mformatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
        mformatter.unitStyle = .medium
        let weight = Measurement(value: weightInKgs, unit: UnitMass.grams)
        return mformatter.string(from: weight)
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).